# Google Cloud Platform HTTPS

Tags: http, https, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I have setup a HTTPS load balancer on Google Cloud Platform which communicates with backends (hosting IIS) using HTTP.

Accessing via the HTTPS URL works fine however, I would like users who try the HTTP URL to be automatically redirected to HTTPS, similar questions have been asked but I can't see anything addressing this when IIS is being used on the backend VMs.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is name of https load balanacer Is it nginx ?  Give full network informaton

Comment: Hi, we are using the default load balancing services provided by Google Cloud Platform. The load balancer is not a separate virtual machine.

Comment: Why dont you use nginx for load balancer. I am not sure which one google is using

Comment: We had hoped it would be achievable without using another VM to run something like nginx. GCP provide the load balancer but we can't see a mechanism for redirects. 

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why you need to nginx on different VM. you can run it on same box with different port though. It all depends upon your network architecture

Comment: The GCP Load balancer is a service and therefore doesn't require a separate VM/box. If we used Ngnix we would need to deploy another VM or host it on an existing VM running other services which is not ideal.

Comment: @Bhupesh Unfortunately currently using HTTPs GCLB do not have feature to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS. There is a [public feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35904733) which also includes some work around and engineering is making efforts to implement this feature. However, you can try configuring IIS to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. [This article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/) may help.

Comment: You should use your web server to redirect, there are no option to setting redirection on GCP.

Answer (score 0):

In the load balancer's frontend configuration tab, there is a check box to enable "HTTP to HTTPS redirect"
[image]